# Cannot Remove Sidebar from Archive Pages in Wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have a theme that I am developing using the _s (aka: underscores) theme.

I do not want my archives to include the `sidebar.php` file.

- My archive.php and paged.php files do not have the sidebar.php
  included.
- I created a home.php file which includes the `get_sidebar()`
  function, and edited my index.php to not include that function.

I'm still seeing my sidebar when I click "Older Posts" on my site which brings me to: `MYDOMAIN/?paged=2` -- this is not what I want.

Specific archive pages (such as for months and categories) do not display the sidebar, which is what I want.

I only want the sidebar to appear on the front page of the site.

I checked the body tags on my home page and on the paged "Older Posts" archive pages to determine what template is being rendered.

Home page:

```
<body class="home blog">
```

paged "Older Posts" archive page:

```
<body class="home blog paged paged-2">
```

This leads me to believe they are both using the home.php template. How can I get those pages to use a different template?

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A friend helped me resolve this issue and I thought I'd share our solution. In order to make sure the sidebar appeared only on the front page of the blog and not appear on the `?paged=` pages, we added some conditional statements around the call to the sidebar on `home.php`:

```
<?php if ( !is_paged() ) { ?>
    <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php } ?>
```

Additionally, this code could be added to the sidebar to keep it from appearing on other pages such as category pages, single posts, etc. While this wasn't necessary since I had used specific templates for those pages that did not include the sidebar, here it is in case it's useful for others:

```
<?php if ( is_front_page() ) { ?>
    <!-- ALL CODE FOR YOUR SIDEBAR HERE -->
<?php } ?>
```